# Links extending to full 50% flex basis of parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My problem is in the contact section, that even though my icons are only a few hundred pixels wide, the links extend themselves across the whole half of the page. Please help!

Here is my HTML, and here's some of the CSS:
(There's more styles in my project of course, but these are the only elements that have positioning/flexbox styles on them).

```css
.panel__inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shows {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.contact {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  align-self: center;
}

.contact__icon {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-3 heading" id="shows">
  <div class="panel__inner">
    <section class="shows">
      <h1 class="shows__heading">upcoming shows</h1>
      <ul class="shows__list">
        <li class="shows__item">
          <p class="shows__date">Friday August 18st</p>
          <p class="shows__local">Wild Wings Sandhills</p>
        </li>
        <li class="shows__item">
          <p class="shows__date">Saturday August 26th</p>
          <p class="shows__local">Wild Wings Vista</p>
        </li>
        <li class="shows__item">
          <p class="shows__date">Friday September 8th</p>
          <p class="shows__local">Wild Wings Augusta</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="contact">
      <ul class="contact__list">
        <li class="contact__item">
          <a href="mailto:bandunderthesunsc@gmail.com" target="_top" class="contact__link"><img class="contact__icon contact__icon--envelop" src="assets/envelope.svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="contact__item">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/BandUnderTheSun/" class="contact__link"><img class="contact__icon contact__icon--facebook" src="assets/facebook-logo.svg" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="contact__item">
          <a href="" class="contact__link"><img class="contact__icon contact__icon--instagram" src="assets/instagram-logo.svg" /></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you everyone in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ul` and `li` descendants of your `.contact` element are block-level elements. Therefore, they will naturally extend to 100% of the parent (which has `flex-basis: 50%`, in this case).

If you don't want the list items to take full width, either:

1. change the `ul` to `inline-block`, or
2. add `display: flex` to `.contact`,

so the width of the list items is based on the content instead.

Both options are illustrated here:

```css
.panel__inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shows {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.contact {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  align-self: center;
  /* option 1
  display: flex;
   */
}

.contact__icon {
  max-height: 100px;
}

/* option 2 */
.contact__list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.contact__list>li {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-3 heading" id="shows">
  <div class="panel__inner">
    <section class="shows">
      <h1 class="shows__heading">upcoming shows</h1>
      <ul class="shows__list">
        <li class="shows__item">
          <p class="shows__date">Friday August 18st</p>
          <p class="shows__local">Wild Wings Sandhills</p>
        </li>
        <li class="shows__item">
          <p class="shows__date">Saturday August 26th</p>
          <p class="shows__local">Wild Wings Vista</p>
        </li>
        <li class="shows__item">
          <p class="shows__date">Friday September 8th</p>
          <p class="shows__local">Wild Wings Augusta</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="contact">
      <ul class="contact__list">
        <li class="contact__item"><a href="mailto:bandunderthesunsc@gmail.com" target="_top" class="contact__link">test<img class="contact__icon contact__icon--envelop" src="assets/envelope.svg"></a></li>
        <li class="contact__item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/BandUnderTheSun/" class="contact__link">test test<img class="contact__icon contact__icon--facebook" src="assets/facebook-logo.svg"/></a></li>
        <li class="contact__item"><a href="" class="contact__link">test test test<img class="contact__icon contact__icon--instagram" src="assets/instagram-logo.svg"/></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Micael_b ! I understand your solutions, and they SHOULD work, however both of them just make my "contact__item"s disappear. As in, they are no longer visible, and when I hover the elements in my inspector, the little tooltip comes up in about the right place, but nothing is being highlighted (the light blue that covers the element you're hovering). I have no idea why. :((

Comment: Make sure there is content in those boxes. With nothing inside, the boxes collapse. That's why I added text and borders to my demo. If there's no content, then you'll need to specify a height and width.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked! I gave the icons height and width!